# Image casting from uint 8 to uint16

Tags: matlab, image-processing, typecast-operator

I want to casting some uint8 RGB images to uint16 RGB type and then after processing  on it (uint16) convert it to uint8 type .I don't what to do (I searched in web very much but any of them doesn't work)

Comment: Do you want the uint16 values to be linear? What is the purpose of the conversion?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [im2uint16()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2uint16.html) Matlab function:

> RGB2 = im2uint16(RGB) converts the truecolor image RGB to uint16,
>   rescaling the data if necessary.